# Adding several data sets in matplotlib.figure subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a question with `matplotlib.figure.Figure`. Is there anyway to plot several sets of data in the same subplot?

I want to show both `dataA` and `dataB` against `time` in the same subplot. Then i wish to return the figure `fig` at the end of the script. So I don't want the plots to show right away but rather that my function is able to return a `Figure`-object.

At the moment I'm doing the following (simplified):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
def getfig():
    fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
    fig.add_subplot(111).plot(dataA,time)
    fig.add_subplot(111).plot(dataB,time)
    return fig
```

I suppose that I'm overwriting the previous subplot at the moment but I don't really know how to add the same datasets in the same subplots...

Comment: Do you mean on the same *axis*? `fig` refers to a big image on which one can have multiple *axes*. Each axis might contain multiple series that e.g. share the same x axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plot to the same *axis*. Usually, I do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_fig(t, a, b, **fig_kwargs):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(**fig_kwargs)
    ax.plot(t, a)
    ax.plot(t, b)
    return fig

fig = create_fig(t, a, b, figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
```